# Rank $ (a) {\aleph_4}^{\aleph_4}, (b) {\aleph_0}^{\aleph_4}, (c) {\aleph_4}^{\aleph_0}, (d) {\aleph_4}, (e) {\aleph_5}, (f) {\aleph_5}^{\aleph_0} $

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If we work in a model of set theory where $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_5$, then Rank in ascending order the following cardinals:

$$
(a) {\aleph_4}^{\aleph_4}, (b) {\aleph_0}^{\aleph_4}, (c) {\aleph_4}^{\aleph_0}, (d) {\aleph_4}, (e) {\aleph_5}, (f) {\aleph_5}^{\aleph_0}
$$

If possible, specify whether there is a strict equality or inequality

My attempt:

the only one I could figure out was: (f) $ {\aleph_5}^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} $.

What will be $\aleph_4$ here?

Comment: What do you mean by "what will be $\aleph_4$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2^{\aleph_4}\le\aleph_4^{\aleph_4}\le(2^{\aleph_4})^{\aleph_4}=2^{\aleph_4}$ etc. (a) and (b) are both $2^{\aleph_4}\ge\aleph_5$ (both (e) and (f), which exceed (d)). Analyze (c) using $\aleph_5=2^{\aleph_0}\le\aleph_4^{\aleph_0}\le2^{\aleph_4\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_4}$, so dropping the brackets $a=b\ge c\ge e=f>d$. But $e=\aleph_5^{\aleph_0}\ge c$, co the second $\ge$ becomes $=$. Since $b=c$ is equivalent to $2^{\aleph_4}=2^{\aleph_0}$, it's undecidable as @spaceisdarkgreen notes (indeed, @tomasz notes [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) shows this).

Comment: It's undecidable whether $b=c$ or $b>c.$

Comment: @tomasz I acknowledged that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. Martin's Axiom plus $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_5,$ which is consistent with ZFC, implies all but (d) are equal to $\aleph_5$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet True, but showing the consistency of MA + $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_5$ is much harder than Cohen-forcing $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_5$ starting with a model of GCH, and showing that the resulting model has this cardinal structure.

Comment: Can we directly use the generalized continuum hypothesis (that for every ordinal $ \alpha, \; \; \aleph_{\alpha+1}= 2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}$, ) to give $c=e=f$?

Comment: @LearningMath No, GCH isn't consistent with $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_5.$ But you can use the fact that Cohen forcing doesn't disturb GCH any more than it needs to. (Or as Daniel noted, the consistency of MA works too.)

Answer (score 2):

$\aleph_4$ is simiply the fourth smallest infinite (well-ordered, if you work in ZF) cardinal.

1. From what you wrote, $\aleph_5=\aleph_5^{\aleph_0}$, so you have one equality.
2. By definition, $\aleph_4<\aleph_5$.
3. Clearly, $\aleph_4^{\aleph_0}\geq 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_5$.
4. On the other hand, $\aleph_5=\aleph_5^{\aleph_0}\geq \aleph_4^{\aleph_0}$.
5. For arbitrary cardinals $2\leq\lambda<\kappa$, $\kappa^\kappa=\lambda^\kappa$.

This is enough to find the order and specify all but one inequality, which is undecidable e.g. by Easton's theorem.