# Exponentiation of infinite cardinals: rules involving $\max\{\kappa_1, \kappa_2\}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Th question is "simple". Let $\kappa_1, \kappa_2$ be two infinite cardinals. We have the simple rules for addition and multiplication:
$$
\kappa_1+ \kappa_2=\kappa_1 \kappa_2=\max\{\kappa_1, \kappa_2\}.
$$
Now do we have a similar rule for
$$
\kappa_1^{\kappa_2}\space?
$$
Could we share some reference for this?

Comment: I found a formula, for arbitrary cardinals $2\leq \lambda <\kappa$ $$\kappa^\kappa=\lambda^\kappa$$, hope it helps!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971604/rank-a-aleph-4-aleph-4-b-aleph-0-aleph-4-c-aleph-4-al

Comment: We also have Hausdorff's $(\kappa^+)^\lambda=\max\{\kappa^\lambda,\kappa^+\}$.

Comment: $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ would be countable.

Answer (score 3):

No. We don't even have a rule for $2^\kappa.$ This is related to the independence of the continuum hypothesis: the value of $2^\kappa$ for regular $\kappa$ is (almost) completely independent of ZFC. For example, $2^{\aleph_0}$ (the cardinality of the reals) can consistently be any cardinal with uncountable cofinality.

See Jech *Set Theory* chapter 5 for information about what we *do* know, for instance, about how to reduce certain cardinal exponentiations to others. (e.g. look at theorem 5.20.) Under GCH, where we assume $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for all $\kappa,$ this leads to a general formula for $\kappa^\lambda$ (theorem 5.15). Under the SCH, $\kappa^\lambda$ is fully determined by the continuum function $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ on regular cardinals (theorem 5.22), but the continuum function on the regular cardinals can still consistently be almost anything. In ZFC alone, there are some nontrivial results on $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}$ and $2^\kappa$ for singular cardinals, though these take the form of bounds under assumptions on what the continuum function looks like for regular $\kappa,$ so this isn't anything approaching a "formula". These results are much harder, though, see for instance Jech chapter 24 or the book by Holz, Steffens, and Weltz.

Comment: Indeed! [For $\kappa$ regular, $2^\kappa$ can be any cardinal with cofinality $>\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Edward was just editing something to that effect in. :)